# Need help Insert big data to cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I need to insert big row(about 1 million row) into table but it's very slow:( I don't know how can to add for quickly, anybody know about this?
Could you help me please! I use `Apache Cassandra 2.1`
This is batch script:

```
mediafire (dot) com (forward slash) view (forward slash) b63lw6rkpkvqbzh (forward slash) shell.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parallelize the work, so divide your script into multiple sub jobs and run them against different nodes (second argument passed to cqlsh). Each node will become the coordinator and, if you have a good partition scheme, the write tasks would be equally distributed among all nodes.

Think about using MapReduce or Apache Spark (with spark-cassandra-connector) on Hadoop if you really need to insert "Big Data" into a Cassandra Cluster.

Comment: Thanks you so much, now I used C# Driver for insert:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the rows in file then I will suggest you to use cassandra copy command as describe [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) or you can use batch command described [here.](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html)